# Two number Sum program in python O(N^2)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am used to write code in c++ but now I am trying to learn python. I came to know about the Python language and it is very popular among everyone. So I thought, let's give it a shot.

Currently I am preparing for companies interview questions and able to solve most of them in c++. Alongside which, I am trying to write the code for the same in Python.  For the things which I am not familiar with, I do a google search or watch tutorials etc.

While I was writing code for my previously solved easy interview questions in python, I encountered a problem.

**Code** : Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Given an array of integers, print the indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

```
def twoNum(*arr, t):
  cur = 0
  x = 0
  y = 0

  for i in range (len(arr) - 1):

      for j in range (len(arr) - 1):
          if(i == j):
              break
          cur = arr[i] + arr[j]
          if(t == cur):
              x = arr[i]
              y = arr[j]
              break

      if(t == cur):
          break

  print(f"{x} + {y} = {x+y} ")

arr = [3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6]

target = 10

twoNum(arr, t=target)
```

So here is the problem: I have defined `x, y` in function and then used `x = arr[i]` and `y = arr[j]` and I m printing those values.

**output coming is : is 0 + 0 = 10**   (where target is 10)

This is I guess probably because I am using `x = 0` and `y = 0` initially in the function and it seems `x` and `y` values are not updating then I saw outline section in VSCode there I saw `x` and `y` are declared twice, once at the starting of the function and second in for loop.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

For reference, here is an image of the code I wrote in C++

[image: This image is my code written in cpp,]

Comment: Why did you add an asterisk on the first parameter? Even in your C++, the parameter's name is just "arr" – the `*` is part of its type. (Read the documentation for details.)

Comment: Change `def twoNum(*arr,t):` to `def twoNum(arr,t):` and your program should work.

Comment: This is a well known problem which can be solved in O(n) rather than O(n^2) as [described here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/) using hashing.

Comment: You will appreciate Python by seeing the above code can be written as: `def twoNum(arr, t): return print(next(f"{i} + {j} = {t} " for i, j in zip(arr, arr) if i + j == t ))`.  You won't get this by first thinking how would I program this in C++., but its okay to start learning but not good to submit such code for an interview.

Comment: I know it can be solved in linear time but I am just learning python for fun. So just want to try Brute force then efficient solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
def twoNum(*arr, t):
```

to this:

```
def twoNum(arr, t):
```

`*` is used to indicate that there will be a variable number of arguments, see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/). It is not for pointers as in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do is to write C code in python.
I would instead try to focus first on how to write python code in a 'pythonic' way first. But for your question - sloving it your way using brute force in python:

```
In [173]: def two_num(arr, t):
 ...:     for i in arr:
 ...:         for j in arr[i + 1: ]:
 ...:             if i + j == t:
 ...:                 print(f"{i} + {j} = {t}")
 ...:                 return
```

Comment: if you want the indices of i and j you can just return arr.index(i), arr.index(j)

Comment: If you want to solve it in a more efficient way you can sort the arr and then go from the edges inwards increment low whenever the sum < t and decrement high whenever sum > t

Comment: I know it can be solved in linear time and in O(NlogN) using sorting but I am just learning python for fun. So just wanted to try Brute force then any other efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to implement a brute force approach using a list comprehension:

```
arr = [1,3,5,7,9]
target = 6

i,j = next((i,j) for i,n in enumerate(arr[:-1]) for j,m in enumerate(arr[i+1:],i+1) if n+m==target)
```

output:

```
print(f"arr[{i}] + arr[{j}] = {arr[i]} + {arr[j]} = {target}")

# arr[0] + arr[2] = 1 + 5 = 6
```

Perhaps even more pythonic would be to use iterators:

```
from itertools import tee
iArr = enumerate(arr)
i,j  = next((i,j) for i,n in iArr for j,m in tee(iArr,1)[0] if n+m==target)
```

When you get to implementing an O(n) solution, you should look into dictionaries:

```
d   = { target-n:j for j,n in enumerate(arr) }
i,j = next( (i,d[m]) for i,m in enumerate(arr) if m in d and d[m] != i )
```